# Android: Volley NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-volley

We have recently updated our app to targetSDK 28. It has been working fine, but one user keeps getting a crash as soon as he runs the application. Here it is, as seen on our google play crash reports:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest (HurlStack.java:109)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest (BasicNetwork.java:97)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run (NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

It is happening for a Sony Xperia, Android 9. 
It seems to be related to a call we do as soon as the app opens (volley), but we cannot reproduce the issue internally so its hard to pinpoint exactly what is going on.

How can I solve this?

Update: Ok, so this is a wild shot in the dark, but according to this I need to update my manifest: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

We do use google play services for location, so hoping this fixes this issue. Will update later.

Comment: Is your application using multidex?

Comment: No I am not using multidex. I've seen a few people mention it while trying to resolve the issue, but figured its not that since it is referencing volley in the stack trace. Honestly, it is the first time I've heard of multidex (I'm still noob at Android), so I don't know if it might be related somehow. Also, it hasn't seemed to affect anyone else, but this one user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution: Put

```
< uses-library
android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
android:required="false" />
```

In the Application object in the AndroidManifest.